# WPF Centering Pinch to Zoom with LayoutTransform

Tags: .net, wpf

**UPDATE 1**
I believe I need to set the Vertical and Horizontal offset's of the ScrollViewer based on the Manipulation Origin value to keep the image under the "pinch". However, I'm having the trouble with how to calculate those values.

---

As part of a larger application, we want users to be able to pinch-zoom and drag to pan an image inside of a scroll viewer. What I have below will allow panning and pinch-to-zoom. However, the zoom seems to take place from the upper left, and I want it centered under the "pinch". How can I modify this code to do that? 
I've found examples that do this perfectly with RenderTransform, but can't figure out how to do it with LayoutTransforms.

Here is my xaml setup:

```
   <ScrollViewer Name="MainScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  >
        <Image Name="MainImage" Source="/test.jpg" Stretch="None" IsManipulationEnabled="True">
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTrans"/>
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
        </Image>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
Private Sub MainImage_ManipulationStarting(sender As Object, e As ManipulationStartingEventArgs) Handles MainImage.ManipulationStarting
    e.ManipulationContainer = MainScrollViewer
    e.Handled = True
End Sub


Private Sub MainImage_ManipulationDelta(sender As Object, e As ManipulationDeltaEventArgs) Handles MainImage.ManipulationDelta
    Dim delta = e.DeltaManipulation
    Dim element = TryCast(e.Source, FrameworkElement)
    If element IsNot Nothing Then
        'Apply Scale Value
        ScaleTrans.ScaleX *= delta.Scale.X
        ScaleTrans.ScaleY *= delta.Scale.Y

        'Panning
        MainScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(MainScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + delta.Translation.X * -1)
        MainScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(MainScrollViewer.VerticalOffset + delta.Translation.Y * -1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the transform's center point.

```
<ScrollViewer Name="MainScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  >
    <Image Name="MainImage" Source="/test.jpg" Stretch="None" IsManipulationEnabled="True">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTrans" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If you need it to be relative to where the pinch is, do it code behind. Like the xaml version, you change the `CenterX` and `CenterY` properties of `ScaleTransform`. However, do note that these two properties are not point values, but rather values from `0.0` to `1.0` relative to itself. `CenterX = 0.0`/`CenterY = 0.0` refer top left, while `CenterX = 1.0`/`CenterY = 1.0` is bottom right. You need to do some calculation on your own.

Comment: I calculated the CenterX/Y values from e.ManipulationOrigin, however that doesn't appear to work. I feel like we also have to change the values of the ScrollViewer's Vertical and Horizontal offset values. But I can't figure out how to calculate the offsets correctly.

Comment: The `CenterX` and `CenterY` properties **are** point values: _Typically, you set CenterX and CenterY to the center of the object that is scaled: (Width/2, Height/2)._ [How to: Scale an Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-scale-an-element#example)